# Symfony controller always returns response. How to handle a web beacon?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've used symfony for many applications, and understand the Controller request->response model. I am implementing a javascript based web beacon that sends a POST to a url handled by my symfony application, with a payload of data. There is no response required or accepted for the web beacon request. It is a one-way deal, kind of like logging.

How can this be implemented in Symfony? I need to accept a request, access the database (I use doctrine) but NOT provide a response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an empty response e.g. `return new Response(null, 204);`  204 is the HTTP statuscode for no-content (successfully processed the request and is not returning any content)

Comment: Didn't know about this! Excellent response, much appreciated.